# Use of change of variables in one dimension (u-sub), and its relation to the definition of a differential.

Tags: calculus, substitution, change-of-variable

I wanted to look more closely at the change of variables technique for integrals (u-sub) since it showed up in a physics problem I was trying to solve. I feel like change of variables sort of shows the following definition of a differential
$$du=f'\left(x\right)dx=\frac{du}{dx}dx$$
This identity was shown to me in Calc 1, and it is frequently used to perform u-sub. From what I know, if $u=f(x)$ in an integral, then $du=f’(x)dx$, and that can be substituted in. I recently looked at the proof for u substitution, and neither the definition of a differential, or a substitution, are really used in it though.
if:
$$\frac{d}{dx}F\left(φ\left(x\right)\right)=f\left(φ\left(x\right)\right)φ'\left(x\right)$$
Then:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f\left(φ\left(x\right)\right)φ'\left(x\right)dx=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d}{dx}F\left(φ\left(x\right)\right)dx$$
$$=F\left(φ\left(b\right)\right)-F\left(φ\left(a\right)\right)$$
$$=\int_{φ\left(a\right)}^{φ\left(b\right)}f\left(u\right)du$$
While this proof does ‘undo’ the chainrule, the substitution $u=φ(x)$ is never used, and neither is the definition of a differential. Thats odd to me since those tools are used to perform u sub. I thought u-sub would work in the following way:
Given:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f\left(φ\left(x\right)\right)φ'\left(x\right)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(φ\left(x\right)\right)\frac{dφ}{dx}dx$$
If $u=φ\left(x\right)$, then $du=\frac{dφ}{dx}dx$ by the definition of a diffrential
Substituting in:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f\left(φ\left(x\right)\right)φ'\left(x\right)dx=\int_{φ\left(a\right)}^{φ\left(b\right)}f\left(u\right)du$$
I’ve always thought that if you change from $dx$ to $du$, then the bounds should now be in terms of $u$. Now that I think about it, I’m not sure why that's rigorously done. It seems more clearer with the first proof of change of variables, but that proof doesn’t use the definition of a differential. I guess I’m asking this because I was originally trying to derive the equation for change in kinetic energy from the following integral:
$$m\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}adx$$
I was given the following justification for rewriting the differentials:
If $x=x(t)$, then $dx = \frac{dx}{dt}dt$
so:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}dx = \frac{dv}{dt} \frac{dx}{dt} dt$$
$$=\left( \frac{dv}{dt} dt \right) \frac{dx}{dt}$$
Using the definition stated above, $dv=\frac{dv}{dt}dt$. Substituting in gives us:
$$= \frac{dx}{dt} dv$$
Changing the bounds from x to v, we get:

$$m\int_{v\left(x_{1}\right)}^{v\left(x_{2}\right)}vdv\ =\ \frac{1}{2}mv\left(x_{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}mv\left(x_{1}\right)^{2}=KE_f-KE_i$$
If I accept the definition of a differential this makes sense, but as I said I don’t really know why the bounds are changed.
Am I misusing the definition of a differential that I assumed at the beginning? Is the definition of a differential really being used in change of variables? Or is it just a trick that's used to set it up? Thanks

Comment: The substitution $u = \phi(x)$ is used in the first proof in the last step. $F(\phi(b)) - F(\phi(a)) = F(b_1) - F(a_1)$ where $b_1 = \phi(b)$ and $a_1 = \phi(a)$. And $F(b_1) - F(a_1) = \int_{a_1}^{b_1} f(u)\,\mathrm du$. In the end, you get the $\phi$ in the bounds

Comment: @AndrewLi I guess that is true, though I didn't really think of it as a substitution. I just thought of that as using FTC. I'm interested in the part where you differentiate to get du=phi'(x)dx